# Wireless network card not working on Acer E5-574G

Tags: wireless, laptop

Wifi doesn't work on my Acer E5-574G. When I boot into the live USB session it looks as wifi is disabled. Meanwhile I do have ethernet connection. My laptop has a: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 card. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. I've checked for additional drivers but no wireless network card driver shows up.
Here is the output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e09a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working correctly.